# Import/export views

Tags: views, 8, importing-exporting

I am currently migrating a Drupal 6 website to Drupal 8. There is no single way to import views. It seems there is no import path in Drupal 8 as in Drupal 6 to do this one by one.

What's the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently (D8.4 october 2017) no migrate update path for views (D6 or D7) to D8. It doubful if this will ever happen because of the complexity of views. I.e. missing views handlers, changed base tables, etc
More info here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2500547

Some work was done on a contrib module for this d.o/project/migrate_views , but it is doubtful if this will ever be finished.

There is basically no other solution than to rebuild your views in the new D8 site. Luckily this is a lot easier than building them on D6 was.

Issues with migration page ( https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/known-issues-when-upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-7-to-drupal-8)  also states:

> Views are not yet migrated.